# Powershell script running in Task Scheduler not producing results

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to run a Powershell script file as a Scheduled Task in Windows Server 2012. The script selects events in Event Viewer using an xml filter and saves them into a text file. The script file is named Sugar2SvcNowLog.ps1 and contains this text:

`Get-WinEvent -FilterXml ([xml] (Get-Content "Desktop\Sugar2SvcNow.xml")) | format-table ProviderName, TimeCreated, Id, LevelDisplayName, message -wrap -autosize | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\yvoloshin_pdadmin\Desktop\Sugar2SvcNowLog  $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss).txt"`

This script creates a text file exactly as intended when I run it in the Windows Command Prompt like this:

`powershell -file "C:\Users\yvoloshin_pdadmin\Desktop\Sugar2SvcNowLog.ps1"`

Then, I've set up a Task Scheduler job where the program to run was set as `"powershell"` and the arguments are

`-file "C:\Users\yvoloshin_pdadmin\Desktop\Sugar2SvcNowLog.ps1"`

When the job runs, the status is shown as "the operation completed successfully". But, a text file is not generated. How can the operation be completed successfully if the file is not generated? What should I do differently?

Answer (score 1):

Your script is referring to `Desktop`.

However, when run from the Task Scheduler there is no user login and no desktop.

I suggest putting the file `Sugar2SvcNow.xml` in some folder and supplying
its full path in the script.